# Hidden date field setting attributes to nil in rails console (but not in the database)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, ruby-on-rails-4, null, hidden-field

I'm trying to pass the current date as a hidden field in my form. The problem is that the date gets saved to the database, yet when I try to access it, it is nil.

In my schema:

```
t.date     "spotlight_start_date"
t.date     "newsletter_start_date"
t.date     "social_media_promotion_start_date"
t.date     "personalized_campaign_start_date"
```

The form: (irrelevant stuff is omitted)

```
<%= form_for @job do |f| %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :spotlight_start_date, value: Time.current %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :social_media_promotion_start_date, value: Time.current  %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :newsletter_start_date, value: Time.current %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :personalized_campaign_start_date, value: Time.current %>
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The console: (date attributes have been saved to the database)

```
...spotlight_start_date: "2016-01-18", newsletter_start_date: "2016-01-18", social_media_promotion_start_date: "2016-01-18", personalized_campaign_start_date: "2016-01-18">
```

When I try to access the date values I get nil:

```
@job.spotlight_start_date
=> nil
```

What's going on? My thoughts are maybe that the hidden fields are saving the date as a string, which is why the rails console thinks that it's nil. I have tried 'Time.now', and putting 'as :date' in the hidden fields with no success.

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Can you post a dump of the entire @job object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your console type     `@job.spotlight_start_date.valid?`

if false then type `@job.spotlight_start_date.errors.full_messages`
 and it should print what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I am stupid! I had set class methods in my model with the same name as the date attributes. The attributes were being overridden by the methods. Don't I feel like a fool!

Thank you so much for the help guys!

Comment: No problem!..did the error messages point you in the right direction at all? Throw a vote my way if it did please! Glad you sorted it though.

Comment: Honestly, I just spotted it myself but it was good to remember that I can do this when I have problems in the future. Thanks again!